# Multi Valued filed value count in Apache SolrCloud

Tags: java, apache, solr, solrj, solrcloud

I have a multi - valued field called country which has multiple values (one in a doc). Is there any way I could get the count of a the countries. Basically I have to get the TopTalkers from this. I'm new to SolrCloud and any help will be appreciated.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Using Faceting will give you all the values for a specific field](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html) and their counts.

You can then use these values with `fq` to filter your result set.

Comment: tried with facets. but could not get the right way using SolrJ. Used groups. got the results. thank you for your help